# Nativescript: How to extend ObservableArray?

Tags: typescript, nativescript

Why do I get the following error ?

> Generic type 'ObservableArray requires 1 type arguments(s)

This is my code :

```
import {ObservableArray} from 'data/observable-array';

export class BaseCollection<T> extends ObservableArray {
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the type, so change you code too:

```
import {ObservableArray} from 'data/observable-array';

export class BaseCollection<T> extends ObservableArray<T> {
}
```

and you shouldn't get that issue.